# first function in Spark when using pivot

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am not sure why the first("traitvalue") in the output data frame query works below.What does first("traitvalue") here mean ? Please advise.

**input data frame:**

```
   val df = sc.parallelize(List(("1","NA","action","Heavy", "NY"),("1","NA","comedy","light", "NY"),("1","NA","horror","light", "NY"),("1","NA","horror","light", "KY"),("2","NA","horror","light", "NY"))).toDF("ban","yr_mon","genre","traitvalue","state")

+---+------+------+----------+-----+
|ban|yr_mon| genre|traitvalue|state|
+---+------+------+----------+-----+
|  1|    NA|action|     Heavy|   NY|
|  1|    NA|comedy|     light|   NY|
|  1|    NA|horror|     light|   NY|
|  1|    NA|horror|     light|   KY|
|  2|    NA|horror|     light|   NY|
+---+------+------+----------+-----+
```

**output dataframe**

```
df.groupBy($"ban",$"state").pivot("genre").agg(first("traitvalue")).show


+---+-----+------+------+------+
|ban|state|action|comedy|horror|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
|  2|   NY|  null|  null| light|
|  1|   NY| Heavy| light| light|
|  1|   KY|  null|  null| light|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a little trick since the example is using agg with pivot but not a numeric function. Using categorical values you may encounter more than one such entry, so it takes the first such entry. Often there is no such issue. E.g. two traits. Hence this approach.